# Monthly average from daily data

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset of energy efficient smart AC units. Each one has an ID, and each unit has daily data that represents the cost saved (in dollars) for each day.

I want to create a bar graph that shows the average savings, per month, per unit. I'm really struggling, however. AVG([Elecsavingscost]) only gets me the average daily savings in a given month. SUM([Elecsavingscost]) * 30 gets me pretty close to what I want, but of course, not all months have 30 days.

Is there a more intelligent way to do this? I'm presuming it's possible...

Comment: What happens if you have sum([ElectSavingsCost]) and use a time dimension at a month level? That should do what you want because the sum() function works at whatever level of granularity you have set up in your rows and/or columns.

Comment: Would you be able to share a sample dataset?

Comment: Read about Tableau's LOD calculations